# How to put a button at center of column in stackpanel

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, grid, stackpanel

I am c# silverligth developer.
I have a grid which contains 1 row and 3 columns.Inside each column i have a stackpanel and on that stackpanel i display the textblock.I do so because it looks good and i have more space and i can display more then 1 item in 1 cell of grid using this stackpanel.
My code to do so is:

```
TextBlock txtblkLabel = new TextBlock();
txtblkLabel.Text = param.Label;
StackPanel sp1 = new StackPanel();
sp1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
sp1.Children.Add(txtblkLabel);
sp1.Width = 50;
sp1.Height = 50;

Grid.SetRow(sp1, LoopCount);
Grid.SetColumn(sp1, 2);
g.Children.Add(sp1);
```

Now the display is at the top left but i want to have this text display at center.

**How to achieve it in c# code (not xaml) ?**

Comment: @Sajeetharan text block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
   txtblkLabel.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
   txtblkLabel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
   txtblkLabel.TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have Controls aligned in the middle of the StackPanel. StackPanel is not meant to have controls being centered in it. It is meant to have controls stacked in it, i.e. one after another.

You could either fill your StackPanel with the TextBlock and than have text centered that way or you could use another Grid instead of StackPanel or some other solution...

Comment: is it possible to have grid inside the particular cell of grid ?code you please give me saple for that in c# code

Comment: You just need to replace your StackPanel control with Grid. Of course you need also to set some columns and rows and other stuff on the grid. How about you try it yourself and if you do not manage to get it working I will gladly help you out. This might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx

Comment: your answer is good but sajeentharans anser worked  at the moment.